# Can my early-2008 Macbook Pro run OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

Like the question says I have an early-2008 Macbook Pro and I want to know if it will run Mavericks before I get it.

Also, if it won't run Mavericks what is the highest OS X version it will run?

Comment: If you are running at least 10.6 and have the App Store, you will see Mavericks available as an update.  If your MacBook Pro can't run Mavericks you won't see it as an update.  Are you running 10.6 or higher?

Comment: @Mr.Mel It does in fact show up as an update on incompatible macs. I have downloaded it before, and then ran into compatibility issues after it finished.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. [According to Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5842?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) these are minimal system requirements:

> To install Mavericks, you need one of these Macs:
>
> Mac (Mid-2007 or later)
>
> MacBook (13-inch Aluminum, Late 2008), (13-inch, Early 2009 or later)
>
> MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid-2009 or later),
>
> MacBook Pro (15-inch or 17-inch, Mid/Late 2007 or later)
>
> MacBook Air (Late 2008 or later)
>
> Mac mini (Early 2009 or later)
>
> Mac Pro (Early 2008 or later)
>
> Xserve (Early 2009)
>
> Your Mac also needs:
>
> OS X Mountain Lion, Lion, or Snow Leopard v10.6.8 already installed 2
>   GB or more of memory 8 GB or more of available space